# Name for branch of mathematics related to finding the most efficient route

Tags: math, routes, scheduling

What's the name of the branch of mathematics for establishing the most efficient route? For example, the study of a post delivery route with the least footsteps.

Comment: It seems like you are looking at a variant of the travelling salesman problem (TSP), an optimization problem in *graph theory*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research. There's an SE for it: https://or.stackexchange.com/